# Are there any non-Shimano Hollowtech II compatible cranksets?

Tags: crankset, bottom-bracket

My power meter is Hollowtech II and I need to replace the crankset. So I’m looking at Shimano cranksets. Were there ever, or are there now, any Hollowtech II compatible cranksets made by any other manufacturer so I can broaden my search?

Edit: My power meter is a left arm XTR M980 and I have it on a Claris crankset. I didn’t include this in the initial question because Stages says this can’t be done. But it’s done and works and I’ve put at least a thousand miles on it.

**But the thing I’m looking for specifically is a 165mm hollowtech ii crankset with 130mm bcd**. Once I find it I’ll sort out the q-factor. But I’m starting to think that it’s time to get a new power meter.

Comment: Which power meter do you have and which aspect of Hollowtech II do you need to be compatible?

Comment: Presumably you have a left crank power meter, with a Shimano Hollowtech II pinch bolt attachment? It's not explicit in the question but would help to know

Comment: @Michael XTR M980 left arm, currently mounted on a Claris crankset.

Answer (score 4):

Of course, but be aware that there are patents (for the design) and trademarks (for the name Hollotech 2) applicable and the compatibity might be in two separate aspects.

The first aspect is the compatibility of the cranks and the bottom bracket. Here it is enough that the crank spindle of the correct 24 mm diameter and the right length. FSA Megaexo 24mm cranks are often reported to be compatible with Hollowtech II bottom brackets. However, that probably does not help you with your powermeter and also, some say [they can be up to 24.07](https://wheelsmfg.com/crankset-tech) and hence not compatible. There is also Rotor3D 24 mm. So they are all 24 mm, but manufacturing tolerances may cause some problems.

The other aspect is the connection of the left crank to the spindle. That may be applicable for powermeters that are sold on a left crank. I fear you are out of luck here. If you have a Hollotech left crank, it must go on a Hollowtech II spindle. Also, be aware of the road/MTB difference here, for example [this left crank powermeter vendor](https://support.stagescycling.com/en/support/solutions/articles/1000037929-how-do-i-find-out-if-my-crank-is-compatible-with-a-stages-power-meter-) has a disclaimer about that and about XTRs. The interface is covered by Shimano patents, the name by Shimano trademarks, and is not, to my knowledge, produced and sold by anyone else.

Comment: Thanks for the info. FWIW, my power meter is a Stages XTR m980 and I’ve got it on a Claris crankset. The Q factor is the same, so I don’t know what they are talking about with the reference to offset.

Comment: @jqning I was assuming you had something like Stages. I cannot offer any comment regading the usability of XTR on road groupsets although they would probably recommend the 105 one instead. It is good that it works for you.